# html2canvas doesn't work with cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, canvas, html2canvas

I generate a canvas with html2canvas, on the pc browser it works, but on my android app (built with cordova) it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it won't work with current Cordova implementation without some hacking. HTML2Canvas requires the script you are executing to be run on HTTP protocol, Cordova/ PhoneGap runs on FILE and recently they switched to CDVFILE protocol.